# How to validate the changes in a webpage after reloading the webpage through selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, reload

I need to constantly reload a web page as quickly as possible and check, if something has changed. But when I tried the following, it didn't work.

I used something like this:

```
while True:
    driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl()) 
    source = driver.page_source
    -- checking for change --
```

while using the Edge webdriver (it was the fastest one), but when the change already occured, the webdriver was still getting the old version of the page.

I don't know if the driver can save the page in cache or something, but I need to make sure, that I will always get the current version. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you call `driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl())` and not simply `driver.refresh()`?. I can't check it right now, but I suspect that it can solve the problem...

Comment: Also, I wonder what are you trying to archive by comparing the page source? Is it to check if the entire page has changes or is it to detect small change that may not even be visible to the end user? Note also that different browsers implement the page_source differently: some return the current state of the DOM, while others return the source exactly as it was received from the server when loaded.

Answer (score 0):

While you invoke `get()` method again on the `getCurrentUrl()` before you pull out the `page_source` to *check for the change*, it is worth to mention that though the *WebClient* may have achieved **'document.readyState'** equal to **"complete"** at a certain stage and *Selenium* gets back the control that doesn't guarantees that all the associated *Javascript* and *Ajax Calls* on the new page have completed. Until and unless the *Javascript* and *Ajax Calls* associated with the *DOM Tree* gets completed the page is not completely rendered you may not be able to track the intended changes.

An ideal way to *check for changes* would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set as [**title_contains**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) as follows :

```
while True:
    driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl())
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.title_contains(("full_or_partial_text_of_the_page_title")))
    source = driver.page_source
    -- check for change --
```

**Note** : While **Page Title** resides within the `<head>` tag of the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) a better solution would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) for the visibility of an element which will be present in all situations within the `<body>` tag of the [**DOM Tree**](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as follows :

```
while True:
    driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl())
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_of_element_present_in_all_situation")))
    source = driver.page_source
    -- check for change --
```